# ввод данных в массив при помощи курсора

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, занимаюсь попытками создания крестиков-ноликов. Сейчас их ввод осуществляется путём указания индекса элемента массива. Возможно ли в дальнейшем вводить изначально заданные данные при помощи курсора? Если да, то каким образом. Заранее спасибо

Comment: на чем планируете писать ui?

Comment: @Sergei Mikhailovskii, Будет интереснее - если самим рисовать по событию мышки ;)

Comment: Добавьте код, кого что у вас есть